# Proper way of vertical spacing before/after environments

Tags: spacing

I am trying to typeset my thesis. I have to put predefined vertical space before and after some specific environments like equation and table. Since there are many instances of these environments I do not want to put space manually. I also do not want to define a new environment like

```
\newenvironment{equ}{\vspace{1cm}\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}\vspace{15mm}}
```

I think the above approach is ugly. I think I have to redefine the environments but

```
\renewenvironment{equation}{\vspace{1cm}\begin{equation}}{\end{equation}\vspace{15mm}}
```

does not work. What is the best way of setting space before and after some specific environments?

UPDATE

I found a solution.

Comment: your redefinition does not work because you're nesting the environment you're redefining into its definition (`equation`)... besides both examples have the same definition...

Comment: @henrique If I can find a way to shut down or suspend recursion, my problem will be solved. I think that this is a very basic problem but I cannot find any solution. And yes both examples have the same definition because that is what I want to accomplish.

Comment: I don't know if I understand what you mean by that... I suggest you check your class file to see how the `equation` environment is defined and then redefine it to add space (actually, the first approach seems ok). You can't define an environment that relies on itself.

Comment: I am not experienced on these kind of modifications so I did not want to delve deeper into the code. I solved the problem for now using `\let` and `\renewenvironemnt`. But I will keep your approach in my mind for future reference.

Comment: Instead of an explicit `\vspace{1cm}` normally you should use one of the three standard LaTeX macros `\smallskip`, `\medskip` and `\bigskip` (or multiple of them). They are designed to fit the font size. However, I see that you are required to add a specific amount. In that case you shouldn't wonder when the result doesn't look good.

Comment: @Martin thank you for your suggestion. Actually, this is for my thesis and unfortunately it is becoming uglier as I am following the style rules. Btw, should I answer my question and mark the thread as answered for future reference?

Comment: @memin: Yes, you could post your `\let` code as answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I find a solution to the problem. Now I am using the following code:

```
\let\oldequation=\equation
\let\endoldequation=\endequation
\renewenvironment{equation}{\vspace{1cm}\begin{oldequation}}{\end{oldequation}\vspace{15mm}}
```

It is still ugly but it does the job and there are still equation environments present in the document. This also works for tables. However this code does not work if I remove the second line. I do not understand why it does not.

Comment: The reason the second line is needed is that your `\begin{oldequation}...\end{oldequation}` expands to roughly `\oldequation...\endoldequation`.  The first two lines define thes two commands.

Answer (score 16):

Try

```
\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{1cm}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{1cm}
```

You have to place these inside the document, i.e. after `\begin{document}` and before `\end{document}`.

You may further refer to http://www.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/textprocessing/squeeze.html

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but this can be only used for the equation and its float equivalent `\abovecaptionskip` seems to be modifying caption space. I generated a solution using the approach at the bottom of the same page. However, I cannot post the answer right now because of the time limitation.

Comment: I find that this works fine before `\begin{document}` as well.