# How to use a math environment without the vertical extra space?

Tags: math-mode, horizontal-alignment

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Remove vertical space around align](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align)

I would like to center two text lines with equations. Normally, one can do that with the `align*` environment. But I do not want the extra vertical space at the top and the bottom of the formulas (see example below).

An alternative could be to simply center the formulas with `\centerline`. But then, the two equation symbols will not be placed one below the other.

Here is an example:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} 
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document} 
text before % Extra space after this line
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1 \\
  x &= \text{here is a long formula}
\end{align*}
text after % Extra space before this line

text before \\
\centerline{$1 = 1$} \\ % equation symbols not below each other
\centerline{$x = \text{here is a long formula}$} \\
text after
\end{document}
```

Is it possible to use `align*` without the extra vertical space ?

If not, what could be another solution ?

Comment: Have you considered editing the `\abovedisplayskip`?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Remove vertical space around align](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47400/remove-vertical-space-around-align). Also see [Proper way of vertical spacing before/after environments](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22589/proper-way-of-vertical-spacing-before-after-environments)

Answer (score 4):

Add the following lines of code:

```
{\setlength{\abovedisplayskip}{0pt}
\setlength{\belowdisplayskip}{0pt}
\begin{align*}
  1 &= 1 \\
  x &= \text{here is a long formula}
\end{align*}}
```

Enclosing the above in `{}` ensures that the display break adjustments are made local and not global.