# How can I reduce the space around alltt environment blocks?

Tags: spacing, environments

How can I reduce the space around *all* `alltt` environment blocks?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}

Test1
\begin{alltt}
some code
\end{alltt}
Test2

\end{document}
```

This question seems to be relevant but doesn't provide a clean answer:

[Proper way of vertical spacing before/after environments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/22589/proper-way-of-vertical-spacing-before-after-environments?lq=1)

Answer (score 5):

The space is comming from `topsep`, so you need to set this to `0` for this environment.  The easiest way to this is with `\AtBeginEnvironment` from the `etoolbox` package which will keep the change local to the environment:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\AtBeginEnvironment{alltt}{\setlength{\topsep}{0pt}}

\begin{document}

Test1
\begin{alltt}
some code
\end{alltt}
Test2

\end{document}
```

Putting `\showthe\topsep` in the file outside the patched environment, gives

```
> 8.0pt plus 2.0pt minus 4.0pt.
l.14 \showthe\topsep
```

showing its standard value for this document.  This stretchable space was what you were seeing in the original.  The `alltt` environment is built form a `trivlist`.  If you look in the LaTeX source (`texdoc source2e` on most systems), you will see a description of the vertical spacing parameters for such environments.

Answer (score 0):

You could redefine the environment, adding an adjustment of the space at the beginning and the end, which you can still modify by changing the factors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{alltt}
\begin{document}

\let\oldalltt\alltt
\renewenvironment{alltt}{\vspace{-0.75\baselineskip}\begin{oldalltt}}{\end{oldalltt}\vspace{-0.1\baselineskip}}

Test1
\begin{alltt}
some code
\end{alltt}
Test2

\end{document}
```